# hibernate fetch null foreign key records

Tags: hibernate

`class Master {

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "refId")
private Ref ref;

@Column
private String name;
```

}`

`class Ref {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "ref_id_seq")
@GenericGenerator(name = "ref_id_seq", strategy = "native",
parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "ref_id_seq")})
@Column(name = "REfId")
protected Long refId;

```
@Column
String first;

@Column
String last;
```

}`

I would like to issue a query searching both in the Master -> name and Ref -> first/last

SQL:
select count(*) as col_0_0 from Master m_ cross join Ref r_ where m.ref=r_.refId and (upper(m_.first) like '%PPP%' or upper(m_.last) like '%PPP%' or upper(r_.name) like '%PPP%')

we couldn't fetch the records where Foreign key (private Ref ref;) is null and tried with different options like fetch.Lazy, options=true and nullable=true, but no luck..

Does any body have a solution for the above scenario except Named Queries?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.